# is there a way to apply WHERE conditions to only one field in a select?

Tags: sql, oracle

Short of doing something like this

**edited 6/29/2012 at 10:17 AM** 
I realized that my query is a little more complicated than my example query and the current suggestions aren't going to work, but that's my fault. I have created a more accurate query above the original.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
a,
max(b) as b,
(select count(distinct c) as c from d where e=2) as c
FROM d
GROUP BY a
```

**sample data from d**

```
 a | b | c | e
---+---+---+---
 0 | 0 | 0 | 1
 0 | 0 | 0 | 2
 1 | 0 | 0 | 1
 1 | 0 | 0 | 1
```

so for this set of data, where a = 0 c would be a count of 1 (where e==1)
and for a = 1 c would be a count of 2 (where e==1)

**end of edit**

```
SELECT
a,
b,
(SELECT c from d where e=2)
FROM d
```

Or at the least is there a better way of doing this performance wise? Like a union perhaps.

Comment: What is your intent? Where conditions only apply to one field; that's just how it is (e.g. `d.e= 2` -- clearly not applying to fields other than `count`).

Comment: Please show an example of data and what you are trying to do.

Comment: Are you asking that you only want to select c when e is 2, but always select a and b?

Comment: Can you include some example data?

Comment: @Lactose - Why does your query have `e=2` and your description have `e==1`?  Now that you've given the example input, please could you give the example output?

Answer (score 2):

if I understand what you're asking then this would work:

```
SELECT
  a,
  b,
  case
    when e=2 then c
    else null
  end as c
FROM
  d
```

Comment: though looking at this again I believe it would give you multiple null rows if there were multiple instances of e<>2

Comment: I still don't really know what the OP wants.  But this feels more sensible than the other answer.

Answer (score 0):

Based on new Information, try this:

```
SELECT a,
       max(b) as b,
       sum(case when e=2 then 1 else 0 end) as c
FROM d 
GROUP BY a
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it you want to group by `a`.  For each group you want the maximum value of `b`, and you want to know the number of distinct values of `c` in rows where `e=2`.

Other answers have the right idea in using `CASE` but have not addressed that you are looking to count distinct values.  I think this is what you are looking for:

```
SELECT a, MAX(b), COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN e=2 THEN c else NULL end)
  FROM d
  GROUP BY a
```

(Your question at the moment is unclear as to whether the value of `e` you are after is 1 or 2; I went with 2 in the query above.)